# Petals for points near the origin

Tags: complex-dynamics, fixed-points

> Let $P(z)=-z+z^{p+1}$ where $p$ is a positive integer.  How many petals does $P$ have at the origin?

From a few examples in my notes, I noticed the following:

- $-z+z^{14}$ has 13 petals.
- $-z+z^3$ has 4 petals.

I'm not able to find a proof of the result above, but I am able to deduce that there are:

- an $2p$ petals if $p+1$ is odd
- if $p+1$ is even then there are $p$ petals.

Could you provide some intuition, or a sketch of the result?

There is a theorem I'm leaning on to get some information:

> Let $R$ be a rational map and suppose that $R(z)=z+az^{p+1}+...$ near the origin.  Let $\Pi_j$ be the petals of $R$ and for each $j$ let $F_j$ be the component of the Fatou set that contains $\Pi_j$.  Then $R^n(z) \to 0$ and $\arg R^n(z) \to 2\pi k/p$ on $F_k$ and $F_0,...,F_{p-1}$  are distinct components of the Fatou set.

But using this theorem, it only shows me that there should always be $p$ petals (ex, there is a petal in between every $\frac{2\pi k_i}{13}, \frac{2\pi k_{i+1}}{13}$).

Besides getting a sketch of the proof, I have one more questions:

- In the even case, there is an overlap between attracting or repelling petals?

Comment: The theorem that you are leaning on, called the Leau-Fatou flower theorem, doesn't apply directly to your case because your coefficient of $z$ is -1, rather than 1. If $f(z)=-z+z^{p+1}$, you can apply the theorem to 
$$F(z) = f(f(z)) = -(-z+z^{p+1}) + (-z+z^{p+1})^{p+1} = z-z^{p+1} + (-z+z^{p+1})^{p+1},$$
which has the same Julia set as $f$. Now, if you expand the $(-z+z^{p+1})^{p+1}$, term, the first term will be $(-1)^{p+1}z^{p+1}$, which will cancel with the $-z^{p+1}$ term precisely when $p$ is odd. Thus, you'll only have $p$ petals when $p$ is even.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Multibrot_sets#z.5En_.2B_m.2Az

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $P(z)=z^{p+1} - z$ where $p$ is a positive integer.  How many petals does $P$ have at the origin?

In [the parabolic case](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/parabolic) [critical orbit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Critical_orbits) looks like [n-th arm star](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361205/what-is-the-shape-of-parabolic-critical-orbit)

Arms tend to attracting directions near fixed point. Number of attracting petals is equal to n.

So I have checked critical orbits using [this Maxima CAS script](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Critical_orbit_for_f(z)_%3D_z%5E14_-_z.png). Here are examples for p=2 and p=13

[image]

[image]

My results are listed below:

- p = 1  ( degree =  2) there are  2 petals
- p = 2  ( degree =  3) there are  2 petals
- p = 3  ( degree =  4) there are  6 petals
- p = 4  ( degree =  5) there are  4 petals
- p = 5  ( degree =  6) there are 10 petals
- p = 6  ( degree =  7) there are  6 petals
- p = 7  ( degree =  8) there are 14 petals
- p = 8  ( degree =  9) there are  8 petals
- p = 9  ( degree = 10) there are 18 petals
- p = 10 ( degree = 11) there are 10 petals
- p = 13 ( degree = 14) there are 26 petals

so:

- for p odd there are 2*p petals
- for p even there are p petals

Answer (score 0):

> In the even case, there is an overlap between attracting or repelling petals?

It depends what definition of petal you use.  There is no unified definition of petals.

Petal of a flower can be :

- attracting / repelling
- small/alfa/big/

Small attracting petals do not ovelap with repelling petals, but big do. [image]

One can choose [overlapping ( red) or not ( yellow)  petals](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Domains_for_Fatou_coordinate_for_f(z)_%3D_z%2Ba_2z_%5E2%2BO(z%5E3).png)