# Identifying unordered set of complex data as originating from a particular Mandelbrot process?

Tags: fractals, chaos-theory, complex-dynamics

Here is an old question which probably originated back in my high school days.

When iterating the Mandelbrot

$$z_{i+1} = {z_i}^2+c$$

we get a sequence of complex numbers. If we plot these in the complex plane, we can get lots of different looks:

[image]

Now if we ***do not*** have ordered sequence, like a "time series" of these $z_k$ : $\{z_k,z_{k+1},\cdots
,z_n\}$ but instead just a plot like this with a unordered set of positions, can we calculate "backwards" what the original $c$ is?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361205/what-is-the-shape-of-parabolic-critical-orbit

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2538723/petals-for-points-near-the-origin?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score -1):

You are drawing [critical orbit](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/def_cqp#Critical_2) = forward orbit of a [critical point](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/def_cqp#Critical_3).

You ask : can we read/approximate the parameter c from the graph/image of critical orbit ?

I think that it is possible to some extent:

- first image: c is probably from interior of Mandelbrot set main cardioid (=  [internal radius](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/def_cqp#Internal_radius) < 1), with [internal angle](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/def_cqp#internal_2) smaller then  n/8 ( 8 arms , turning clockwise), for example c = 0.345805039440922  +0.097755675960631 i
- last image looks like a periodic orbit with period = 14 , so it maybe center of hyperbolic component with period 14, like for example c = 0.295453572980359  +0.020451548527456 i
- middle image looks like [Siegel disc](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/siegel)

But remember that because of slow dynamics and numerical errors first n-points may look different then images with more points.

The next questions could be :

- how critical orbit is changing when c is moving on the parameter plane?
- [how to move on the parameter plane ?](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/Parameter_plane#How_to_move_on_parameter_plane_?)

HTH

Comment: Those are interesting remarks, sure, but I don't think they actuallly answer OP's question

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki : " can we read/approximate the parameter c from the graph/image of critical orbit ?"Is it  properly read the OP's question ?

Comment: "can we **calculate** (...)"  as you said, we can read the approximate position of eg an attracting fixe point, and from there deduce $c$. but I think it should be doable to find analytically the exact value of $c$ from the data given in OP's question

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki: data give in a question is a plot.